# Deploying an upgradeable contract only deploys 2 contracts and not 3

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment

I have a problem. I've deployed an upgradeable smart contract.
As you know it deploys 3 contracts- admin, proxy and implementation.
I found out that my private key was compromised and I created a new one right away.
I re-deployed that upgradeable contract with my new wallet but it only deployed 2 contracts not 3
And now every time I want to do an upgrade it says "caller is not the owner"
and I have to use my compromised private key in order yo do upgrades.
Can anyone tell me why I deployed only 2 contracts if I was using a completely new private key?
And how do I fix this? Thank you

Comment: Can you share the code used for the deployment?

Comment: Found the problem. Just had to create a new folder from scratch and copy the actual code. Thanks!